# how can I de-reference a memory address in GDB?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

I have the following line in gdb

```
8048dc2       movl  $0x8049a35, 0x4(%esp)
```

I want to know how to de-reference the address $0x8049a35 so I can figure out what it is, how do I do that in GDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example use `x 0x8049a35`. You can also choose a format, see the gdb built-in help. I am puzzled why you didn't read that before asking on SO.

Comment: I've tried both x 0x8049a35 and x/d x 0x8049a35, and it states it's 622879781. I honestly have no idea what it means. Sorry, I didn't know there was a gdb built-in help as I am really new to gdb. My instructor gave us a small list of instructions regarding gdb and told us to use those in the lab. I'll look into the build-in help.

Comment: `x 0x8049a35` should work, the other one would try to use `x` as a number and would indeed show the error you said. What happens for the `x 0x8049a35`?

Comment: Well, what it means we can't know, we only know that's the value in memory.

Comment: ah I see. I'll just look more into it then. Thanks for the help

Comment: Looks like it's a format string, try `x/s 0x8049a35`

Comment: Ah, it returns %d, %d. Thanks, now i know it requires 2 numbers as the solution. thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the bomb :D